# R Extracting following days in time series based on different signals

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

In my example I have a data frame with 3 columns: date, signal and value. Now I want to mutate new columns, which are conditioned on the signals.

If there is a signal on a previous day (`ifelse(lag(signal) == 1`), then give me first following day and in the next column the first and the second following day (`else = NA`). 
 But in this case I have three different signals (`c(1,2,3)`).

I want a dynamic solution. This means that I can very the number of the following days (because in my real case I want to use the next seven following days) and also the number of signals.

Here is my example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(date   = today()+0:10,
             signal = c(0,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,0),
             value  = sample.int(n=11))
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   date       signal value
   <date>      <dbl> <int>
 1 2019-07-23      0     3
 2 2019-07-24      1    11
 3 2019-07-25      0     2
 4 2019-07-26      0     6
 5 2019-07-27      2    10
 6 2019-07-28      0     5
 7 2019-07-29      0     4
 8 2019-07-30      3     9
 9 2019-07-31      0     8
10 2019-08-01      0     1
11 2019-08-02      0     7
```

And here is my desired output:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
   date       signal value   new_col_day1_sig_1  new_col_day2_sig_1  new_col_day1_sig_2  new_col_day2_sig_2  new_col_day1_sig_3  new_col_day2_sig_3
   <date>      <dbl> <int>
 1 2019-07-23      0     3                 NA                   NA                   NA                  NA                 NA                NA
 2 2019-07-24      1    11                 NA                   NA                   NA                  NA                 NA                NA
 3 2019-07-25      0     2                  2                    2                   NA                  NA                 NA                NA
 4 2019-07-26      0     6                 NA                    6                   NA                  NA                 NA                NA
 5 2019-07-27      2    10                 NA                   NA                   NA                  NA                 NA                NA
 6 2019-07-28      0     5                 NA                   NA                    5                   5                 NA                NA
 7 2019-07-29      0     4                 NA                   NA                   NA                   4                 NA                NA
 8 2019-07-30      3     9                 NA                   NA                   NA                  NA                 NA                NA
 9 2019-07-31      0     8                 NA                   NA                   NA                  NA                  8                 8
10 2019-08-01      0     1                 NA                   NA                   NA                  NA                 NA                 1
11 2019-08-02      0     7                 NA                   NA                   NA                  NA                 NA                NA
```

I have already asked the same question, but without the different signals: 
[R Extracting following days after signal in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110805/r-extracting-following-days-after-signal-in-time-series)

Here is a solution for only one signal:

```
anylag <- function(x, n) {
  l <- lapply(1:n, function(i) lag(x, i) == 1)
  Reduce("|", l)
}

df %>% mutate(calculation=ifelse(anylag(signal, 3), value, NA))
```

But now I want to implement the signals.
The solution should look similar to this:

```
signals<-c(1,2,3)

anylag <- function(x, n, signals) {
  l <- lapply(1:n, function(i) lag(x, i) == 1 * signals)
  Reduce("|", l)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution, not elegant but it works:

```
anylag <- function(x, n, s) {
  l <- lapply(1:n, function(i) lag(x, i) == s)
  Reduce("|", l)
}

for(s in signals) {
  for(lag in 1:2) {
    varname <- sprintf("new_col_day_%d_sig_%d", lag, s)
    df <- mutate(df, !!varname := ifelse(anylag(signal, lag, s), value, NA))
  }
}
```

There *are* some cases where for loops are simpler, at least conceptually ;-)

**EDIT:**

Signals which are like "1.5". There are two issues here.

First issue is that if your `signals` column is numeric (i.e., a double / floating point), then you should *never, ever* use `==` or `%in%` to compare its values. Either use `all_equal()`, or – in your case – convert the column to a character vector.

Regarding the sprintf: here you can use `%s` instead of `%d`, then the signal will be interpreted as a character vector. In other cases, you might be interested in `%f` or variants such as `%.2f`. I recommend learning the format of the sprintf function, it is used not only in R.

**EDIT 2:** Sure, you can use lapply instead of for.

```
res <- lapply(signals, function(s) 
          sapply(1:2, function(lag)
             ifelse(anylag(df$signal, lag, s), df$value, NA)
        ))
res <- do.call(cbind, res)
colnames(res) <- expand.grid(1:2, signals) %>% 
  mutate(cn=sprintf("new_col_day_%d_sig_%d", Var1, Var2)) %>% 
  pull(cn)
```

Or using map2 from purrr:

```
cc <- expand.grid(1:2, signals) 
res <- map2_dfc(cc$Var1, cc$Var2, 
   ~ ifelse(anylag(df$signal, .x, .y), df$value, NA)) %>%
    setNames(sprintf("new_col_day_%d_sig_%d", cc$Var1, cc$Var2))
```

Now you can `cbind` the result `res` with your data frame.

There was a reason I chose `for` in this context – it is actually more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, we can write a function which accepts number of days to `lookback` and multiple `signal` values to check for. We then write a nested loop which gives us boolean columns

```
anylag <- function(x, lookback, signal) {
   do.call(cbind, lapply(signals, function(z)
         sapply(seq_len(lookback), function(y) 
           sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) any(x[max(1, i - y) : (i - 1)] == z)))))
}

number_of_days <- 2
signals<-c(1,2,3)
```

and pass the `signal` values to it

```
cols <- c(outer(1:number_of_days, signals, function(x, y) 
              paste0("new_col_day", x, "_sig", y)))

df[cols] <-  anylag(df$signal, number_of_days, signals)
```

Write another function to change values

```
change_values <- function(x, value) {
     ifelse(x, value, NA)
}

df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) change_values(x, df$value))


#   date       signal value new_col_day1_si… new_col_day2_si… new_col_day1_si…
#   <date>      <dbl> <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>
# 1 2019-07-23      0     4               NA               NA               NA...
# 2 2019-07-24      1     8               NA               NA               NA...
# 3 2019-07-25      0    11               11               11               NA...
# 4 2019-07-26      0    10               NA               10               NA...
# 5 2019-07-27      2     7               NA               NA               NA...
# 6 2019-07-28      0     1               NA               NA                1
# 7 2019-07-29      0     3               NA               NA               NA...
# 8 2019-07-30      3     9               NA               NA               NA...
# 9 2019-07-31      0     2               NA               NA               NA...
#10 2019-08-01      0     6               NA               NA               NA...
#11 2019-08-02      0     5               NA               NA               NA...
```